# Problems Using routing-filter beta version 0.4.0.pre

Tags: ruby-on-rails, localization, internationalization, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-routing

I am using the 0.4.0.pre version of the routing-filter for Rails 4 at the suggestion of the person that posted that version in RubyGems. You will not find this version when you do a search on the RubyGems website.  I found out about this when I posted a comment on an existing issue in GitHub.

https://rubygems.org/gems/routing-filter/versions/0.4.0.pre

I am finding differences between this version and the one I currently use in my Rails 3 applications.  I believe it is the latest version 0.3.1.  With this gem the locale is included in my URLs and in the debug info at the bottom when running localhost as expected.  However when I use the 0.4.0.pre version the locales do not show up in URLs or the debug info.  I have links at the top of the header section where a person can select their locale.  When one of those links is clicked the locale appears in the URL.  When I click another link (text or icon) the locale disappears but the locale is set in a cookie (a supposed no no but will keep it for now).  The translations are correct for the selected locale but unless I do something special in my links for the person to know which one they clicked, no one will know the locale.  This is a problem because for now I am setting up the locale files and all of them will be in English until I am able to get translations for the other languages.

Here is the code I have in both applications in application_controller.rb where I set the locale and create a cookie.

```
before_filter :set_locale

private
  def set_locale
    I18n.locale = (params[:locale] if params[:locale].present?) || cookies[:locale] || 'en'
    cookies[:locale] = I18n.locale if cookies[:locale] != I18n.locale.to_s
  end
```

Here is the code I have in config/routes.rb.

```
filter :locale
```

Here is the code for my locale line in my header in my Rails 4 application.  I have similar code in my Rails 3.2.13 application.

```
<%= link_to_unless_current "English", locale: "en" %> <%= link_to_unless_current "Español", locale: "es" %> <%= link_to_unless_current "Français", locale: "fr" %>
```

I'm not sure if the issue is with the 0.4.0.pre gem or if I need to make additional i18n changes in my Rails 4 application. From reading the i18n documentation I'm not seeing anything additional I need to do. There is no specific documentation about 0.4.0.pre so I assume I should be able to do what I am doing with the Rails 3 version of routing-filter.

I have posted this in the issue section for the gem in GitHub.  I have done online searches about using this version of routing-filter but cannot find them.  I think it posted last month.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem has been corrected the problem with the locale not appearing in the URL. However I ended up using the native Rails code for routing since I had two applications in production that I had already rewritten in Rails 4.